# serial foreign key with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

These are my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE Utente (
    ID serial primary key
    name varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE friendship(
    idUtente1 bigint NOT NULL UNIQUE UNSIGNED , 
    idUtente2 bigint NOT NULL UNIQUE UNSIGNED , 
    dataAmicizia date,
    primary key (idUtente1,idUtente2), 
    FOREIGN KEY (idUtente1) REFERENCES Utente(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (idUtente2) REFERENCES Utente(ID)
);
```

My problem is : I cannot create the foreign key because `idUtente1` is serial.

I tried to add AUTO_INCREMENT at both but it's impossible. How can I solve?

Answer (score 2):

SERIAL is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html

`idUtente1` must also be one to match. Except with the AUTO_INCREMENT.

Try this for the table friendship:

```
CREATE TABLE friendship(
    idUtente1 bigint UNSIGNED , 
    idUtente2 bigint UNSIGNED , 
    dataAmicizia date,
    primary key (idUtente1,idUtente2), 
    FOREIGN KEY (idUtente1) REFERENCES Utente(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (idUtente2) REFERENCES Utente(ID)
);
```

Comment: Yes , I know that but if I don't add AUTO_INCREMENT it doesn't work.